# this php is driving me crazy

Tags: php, arrays

i am getting this error at `"$hourtominute = date('H',strtotime($qData\[0\]\['totaltime'\]))*60;"` and it wont tell me where the error is. Its just redmarked. can you please help me. if ur not understanding it please let me know so i can be more exactly. the code has been working for 4 years until last months. cant see why its giving me this error.
i did post a picture aswell.

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEA4s.png)

```
<?php 
$model = Passivatelog::model();
if(!empty($myValue)) { 
    //var_dump($myValue);

    $oPsv = Passivatelog::model();
    $oPsvRep = PassivatelogReport::model();

    $aReport = $oPsvRep->getReportByMachineId($myValue['report_machine']);
    $operator = $aReport['report_operator'];
    $machine = $aReport['report_machine'];
    $date = $aReport['report_date'];

    $aGroupedSteps = $model->getAllSteps();
?>
<div class="col-lg-6">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>Operator:</th>
                <th>Maskinnummer:</th>
                <th>Datum:</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $operator;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $machine;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $date; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr><th></th><th colspan="2">Temperatur</th><th colspan="2">PH Värde</th><th>Konduktivitet</th><th colspan="3">Tid</th></tr>
                <tr><th>Process</th><th>Start</th><th>Stop</th><th>Startvärde</th><th>Diff In/Ut</th><th>Medel</th><th>Start</th><th>Stop</th><th>Totaltid minuter</th></tr>
            </thead>
<?php            
    foreach($aGroupedSteps as $gstep) {
        $qData = $oPsv->getAllData($gstep->log_processname, $aReport['report_date'], $aReport['report_from'], $aReport['report_to']);
                $hourtominute = date('H',strtotime($qData[0]['totaltime']))*60;
                $minutetominute = date('i',strtotime($qData[0]['totaltime']));
                $totaltime = $hourtominute+$minutetominute;
                echo '
            <tr>
                <td>' . $gstep->log_processname . '</td>
                <td>'.$qData[0]['starttemp'].'</td>
                <td>'.$qData[0]['endtemp'].'</td>
                <td>'.(($qData[0]['startph']>0)? $qData[0]['startph']:'').'</td>
                <td>'.(($qData[0]['diffph']>0) ? number_format($qData[0]['diffph'],2) : '' ).'</td>
                <td>'.(($qData[0]['conductivity']>0)? number_format($qData[0]['conductivity'],0) : '').'</td>
                <td>'.$qData[0]['starttime'].'</td>
                <td>'.$qData[0]['endtime'].'</td>
                <td>'.$totaltime.'</td>
            </tr>';
    }
   ?> 
<tfoot></tfoot>
        </table>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php
} else {
    $oPsv = Passivatelog::model();
    $oPsvRep = PassivatelogReport::model();

    $aReport = $oPsvRep->getLatestReport();
    var_dump($aReport);
    $operator = $aReport['report_operator'];
    $machine = $aReport['report_machine'];
    $date = $aReport['report_date'];
    $aGroupedSteps = $model->getAllSteps();
    if(!empty($aGroupedSteps) && !empty($aReport)) {
?>
<div class="col-lg-6">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>Operatör:</th>
                <th>Maskinnummer:</th>
                <th>Datum:</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $operator;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $machine;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $date; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr><th></th><th colspan="2">Temperatur</th><th colspan="2">PH Värde</th><th>Konduktivitet</th><th colspan="3">Tid</th></tr>
                <tr><th>Process</th><th>Start</th><th>Stop</th><th>Startvärde</th><th>Diff In/Ut</th><th>Medel</th><th>Start</th><th>Stop</th><th>Totaltid minuter</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
<?php
        foreach($aGroupedSteps as $gstep) {
                $qData = $oPsv->getAllData($gstep->log_processname, $aReport['report_date'], $aReport['report_from'], $aReport['report_to']);
                $hourtominute = date('H',strtotime($qData[0]['totaltime']))*60;
                $minutetominute = date('i',strtotime($qData[0]['totaltime']));
                $totaltime = $hourtominute+$minutetominute;
                echo '
            <tr>
                <td>' . $gstep->log_processname . '</td>
                <td>'.$qData[0]['starttemp'].'</td>
                <td>'.$qData[0]['endtemp'].'</td>
                <td>'.(($qData[0]['startph']>0)? $qData[0]['startph']:'').'</td>
                <td>'.(($qData[0]['diffph']>0) ? number_format($qData[0]['diffph'],2) : '' ).'</td>
                <td>'.(($qData[0]['conductivity']>0)? number_format($qData[0]['conductivity'],0) : '').'</td>
                <td>'.$qData[0]['starttime'].'</td>
                <td>'.$qData[0]['endtime'].'</td>
                <td>'.$totaltime.'</td>
            </tr>';

        }
        ?>
            <tbody>
            <tfoot></tfoot>
        </table>           
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
            <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: what happens if you put `die(var_dump($qData[0]['totaltime']))` before that line.

Comment: it does not say, thats whats driving me crazy lol

Comment: castis, it just give me that the code under is wrong aka "$hourtominute = date('H',strtotime($qData\[0\]\['totaltime'\]))*60;"

Comment: How can you not have an error message and at the same time have PHP tell you something is wrong? That makes no sense.

Comment: look at my image, i updated it.

its the whole page, nothing more nothing less.

Answer (score 0):

> Data stored in array:  $qData[0]['totaltime'] is not of correct format
>   to be converted to time.

Check **strtotime** function in PHP manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to check for the correct format of the string to be converted and check the data stored in that array whether it matches any of the mentioned formats in the manual.

You may need to cleanse your data, so that it works again, given it used to work before (as you have mentioned) but suddenly stopped working. It is a data related issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will check, ty!

Comment: Their issue is an undefined offset which would cause this error. Please vote to close as a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133)